# Points with 0 $x$-coordinate in $r$-torsion and distortion map

Tags: algebraic-geometry, finite-fields, elliptic-curves, torsion-groups

Suppose I have the curve $E/F_{59}: y^2 = x^3+1$ -i.e. it is supersingular. Hence number of points is $\#E(F_q) = 59+1$ and for $r=3$ (i.e $3\ |\ 60$ but $3^2\not|\ 60$), the embeding degree is $k=2$ and construct the extension $F_q /\langle i^2+1\rangle$ (see the picture).

Now since $59 \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$ I choose the following distortion map $\phi(x,y) = (\zeta_3 x,y)$, where $\zeta_3 = 24i+29$ and $\zeta_3^3 = 1$.

The $r$-torsion and the action of the map $\phi$ over it are painted below:
[image]

The other maps are the trace map(Tr) and anti-trace map(aTr). Now I have this definition

A distortion map on E is an endomorphism $\phi$ of E such that $\phi(P) \notin \langle P\rangle$.

**My question.** Why $\phi$ fails to map the red elements out of their subgroup ? Since it is a distortion map it should not do that, right?

Comment: +1 for including the details. It seems to me that either $\phi$ is not a distortion map or the given definition of a distortion map is wrong. Alas, I'm not familiar with all the definitions. A quick check of related material in Silverman's AEC didn't leave me with the impression that a supersingular curve could not have such automorphisms.

Comment: I mean, the red subgroup of 3-torsion points is obviously stable under $\phi$. If we view the full 3-torsion subgroup as $\Bbb{Z}_3^2$ then  it looks like the matrix of $\phi$ wrt a suitable basis must look like $$\pmatrix{1&1\cr0&1\cr}$$ with the red subgroup being the eigenspace belonging to $\lambda=1$. Why is that a problem? I think I have a chance to learn something here :-)

Comment: [A related thread in MO](https://mathoverflow.net/q/102765/15503). It's still not 100% clear to me what a distortion map is? If it suffices that $P$ and $\phi(P)$ generate $E[m]$ for **some** $P\in E[m]$, then your order three endomorphism is ok. If we need it for **all** $P\in E[m], P\neq0$, then your $\phi$ is not a distortion map.

Comment: And [a related thread from Crypto.SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/310/1077). But, I have yet to find a definition of a distortion map. At this point my guess is that you should not study the 3-torsion with this $\Phi$.

Comment: If I follow [this source](https://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/nitin/courses/scribed2-WS2010-11.pdf) then it is plain that your $\phi$ is not a $3$-distortion map. It probably is an $\ell$-distortion map for primes $\ell\neq3$.

Comment: First, Thank you @JyrkiLahtonen for your interest. The definition for distortion map I've taken from here https://eprint.iacr.org/2006/128.pdf.

Comment: It seems that whenever $q \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$ and curve looks like $y^2=x^3+ax$ then $(x,y) \rightarrow (-x,iy)$ gives a distortion map. On the other hand, whenever $q \equiv  2 \pmod{3}$ and curve looks like $y^2=x^3+a$ then $(x,y) \rightarrow (wx,y)$ gives a distortion map, with $w^3 =1 $. Note that in this cases $q$ satifies both conditions, so we should have two distortion maps, right ?

Comment: Btw, I tested for $\ell = 5$ and this problem is not present in this case.

Comment: Accoding to that definition (D. Charles) $\phi$ is not a distortion map for $\ell=3$.

Comment: Can you point me out where it this specified in the paper? :)

Comment: In the second paragraph he defines a distortion map (wrt prime $\ell$) as an endomorphism such that $\phi(P)$ is not an integer multiple of $P$.

Comment: A ok, I've seen it. Thanks and nice catch. I don't know how I missed that. Hence in this case $\ell = 3$ we never have a distortion map because of that red subgroup (the points there will be mapped trivially hence that integer is $1$), right ?

Comment: But also, the literature says that when the curve is supersingular (which is our case), the distortion map must exist. I don't know whether that is true for any $\ell$ or specific one. In our case it seems that does not exist for $\ell =3$, but for $\ell=5$ exists. I will search the internet deeper.

Comment: I was reading [this paper](https://www.cs.ru.nl/E.Verheul/papers/Joc2004/joc2004.pdf) and at some point (read just below fig.1 page 13), distortion maps in $\ell$-torsion subgroups do not have the points in that subgroup as eigenvectors. Maybe this is why it fails in this case (the points in red subgroup are eigenvectors of $\phi$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that for any $P$ in red subgroup $\phi(P) = P$. Hence the endomorphism (on that subgroup) has an eigenvalue $\lambda = 1$ with the corresponding eigenvectors in the red subgroup.

It seems that distortion maps fail to move out the elements from their subgroup when are defined over their eigenvectors.